# Can't get a collection of elements by class name using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get all elements with class `.genre_prod_title` and printing "OK" in a foreach loop for all elements and "CLICK" when clicked.

EDIT : I'm binding jQuery as $ because I'm developing using WordPress.

```js
(function($) {

  var genre_prod_title_all = $(".genre_prod_title");

  console.log(genre_prod_title_all);

  $(".genre_prod_title").each(function(index) {

    console.log("OK");

    $(this).on("click", function(event) {

      console.log("CLICK");

    });
  });


})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><button class="genre_prod_title" id="film">Film</button></li>
  <li><button class="genre_prod_title" id="magazine">Magazine</button></li>
  <li><button class="genre_prod_title" id="documentaire">Documentaire</button></li>
</ul>
```

But the printing of the variable `genre_prod_title_all` (which is just a test for check if all of the three elements are selected) just show one element, and "OK" and "CLICK" are not printed.

Comment: I've turned your code into a snippet. All three log as expected. The click function works, too.

Comment: I think the problem might be with how you are including the javascript module written in the question. Can you please specify how you're adding your script to the html?

Comment: Made a snippet too can confirm everything is working. I think your function is started before the dom is rendered. Make sure you are triggering the function onload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the function inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.genre_prod_title').each(function(element){
    console.log('ok');
    $(this).on('click',function(event){
        console.log('click')
    });
  })
})
```

You can perform that using pure Javascript like this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.genre_prod_title');
    elements.forEach(function(el, index){
        console.log('ok')
        el.addEventListener('click', function(event){
            console.log('click');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you just have the $ sign misplaced: 
 (function($){
  instead of
  $(function(){